# Xcode 5 and AFNetworking 2.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm pulling my hairs out over this, and can't seem to figure out why AFNetworking, and Xcode 5 don't seem to work together.

I'm using the tutorial seen [here](http://dev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-uirefreshcontrol--mobile-14712) , and for some reason whenever I go to build the actual program it tells me:

No visible

```
@interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector 'setImageWithURL:setPlaceholderImage:'
```

Now I've already imported `AFNetworking.h` into my prefix file, and I've added `MobileCoreServices` and `SystemConfiguration` in too. I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

I'm assuming the error I'm receiving is because Xcode isn't properly linking to the `AFNetworking` library. But how do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is broken out in AFNetworking 2.0.  Use the following #import:

```
#import "UIKit+AFNetworking.h"
```

Comment: Plus, the method is `- [UIImageView setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]`, not `-[UIImageView setImageWithURL:setPlaceholderImage:]`.

Comment: Thank you Tom, I wasn't aware of this. New to all of this. And @Ian that helped too. I can't believe I missed that.